# Having trouble with variables in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, aggregate-functions

I want to mention that I'm new using sql developer and I'm trying to fill a temporary table with two values that are found in two variables, but i'm not able to get it right. I'm hoping that maybe one of you guys could have a better idea.
This is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE
     x NUMBER;
     y NUMBER;
BEGIN
EXEC SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :x FROM (select * from view2 where restituita=1);
EXEC SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :y FROM (select * from view2 where restituita=0);
create global temporary table dateRest (rest number,nerest number);
insert into dateRest values(x,y);
select * from dateRest;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the final results, the query is over complicated -- it only needs to be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN restituita = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN restituita = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM view2;
```

- `EXEC` is TSQL syntax -- `EXECUTE` is PLSQL/Oracle syntax, but neither is necessary
- The colon indicates a bind variable, which is used for supplying a value to a query -- not for retrieving one
- the [creation of the global temp table needs to be run as dynamic SQL when in a stored procedure or anonymous block](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1086033238621) -- really don't recommend the use of temp tables if at all possible.  But the temp table wouldn't be visible for the insertion, much less selection from

Comment: I doubt this will work. I even doubt any of the three statements will work within a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Agree with Codo. You have to have a destination for SELECT in PL/SQL. either you have to open the select as a cursor, or use INTO variables if the SQL returns one and only one row.

Comment: Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Surely OMG is replacing the entire anonymous block, not just the selects within it? Assuming `dateRest` is only being created for this and doesn't actually need to exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you have more errors and problems than lines in your piece of code. It's a mixup of SQL statements, PL/SQL, and variable binding of other languages.

Since you use a *declare/begin/end* block, you're in the PL/SQL world. In the PL/SQL world:

- You cannot use *EXEC*, because it's a short hand for *begin/end* if you're not in PL/SQL.
- You don't need to use colons for variable binding
- You cannot execute a *SELECT* statement without putting the result somewhere
- You cannot execute DDL statements (CREATE TABLE...) directly.
- You usually cannot refer to tables that do not exist when the *begin/end* block is started.

And don't forget to commit.

So the solution probably is: don't use PL/SQL.

```
create global temporary table dateRest (rest number,nerest number);
insert into dateRest(x, y)
  select (select count(*) from view2 where restituita=1),
    (select count(*) from view2 where restituita=0)
  from dual;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should lose the `:` for parameters within (anonymous) procedures.

[edit]

No, I'm wrong. The `:` are not needed when you don't use EXEC. I think your problem lies in creating the table. This is not possible in this way, because PLSQL doesn't support the CREATE TABLE statement. You should use:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ....';
```

Answer (score 0):

The corrected OMG anonymous block would be:

```
DECLARE
   var1 Number;
   var2 Number;
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN restituita = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
     SUM(CASE WHEN restituita = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   INTO var1, var2
FROM view2;

END;
```